# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "Book" at line 1, column 15

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

```
package javaapplication2;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



//jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/LMS


class abc {


public  abc() throws SQLException{


 //ConnectionURL, username and password should be specified in getConnection()


 //ConnectionURL, username and password should be specified in getConnection()
 try {String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/LMS";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"zain","12345");
  System.out.println("Connected! ");

  String sql = "SELECT * FROM BOOK";`enter code here`
 Statement st = conn.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
 String x;
 while(rs.next()){


System.out.println(rs.getString("Password")); 
 }


 } 


 catch (SQLException ex) {
 System.out.println(ex);
 }


} 
}
```

I am getting this any lead? I am trying this thing for hours and not getting any lead :/  plz help. I am making a Library Management System and made Db for it with a column book in it and trying to get data from it.

Comment: I am assuming book is your TABLE not a column

Comment: Are you sure you know which statement is giving you the error? Your pasted code says `BOOK`, your exception message says `Book`. Perhaps you are running different code than you think you are. Make sure you get the full exception information by following http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain . Also, run your program using -Dderby.language.logStatementText=true and look in your derby.log to see *exactly* what SQL is being passed to the database.

Answer (score -1):

Derby is a tricky beast.
Here is a working example of a data retreivale and prep for insert into a Jtable

```
public static final String DRIVER= "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
public static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/LMS";

private  void GetData()throws  SQLException 
{
    Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL,"zain","12345");
    ResultSet result = null; 
    String sql2 = "select * from book"; 
    PreparedStatement ps1 = connection.prepareStatement( sql2, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY) ;
    result = ps1.executeQuery();
    // get number of rows
    result.last();
    int numRows = result.getRow();
    result.first();
    //Get metadata object for result
    ResultSetMetaData meta = result.getMetaData();
    // create an arry of string for the colum names
    colNames = new String[meta.getColumnCount()];
    // store column names in the new col names array
    for( int i = 0; i< meta.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        //get column name
        colNames[i] = meta.getColumnLabel(i+1);

    }
    // create 2 d string array for table data
    tableData = new String [numRows][meta.getColumnCount()];
    // store columns in the data
    for ( int row = 0 ; row < numRows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < meta.getColumnCount(); col++)
        {
            tableData[row][col]= result.getString(col + 1);
        }
        result.next();
    }
    // close statement
    ps1.close();
    connection.close();
} // end get data
```

To insert into a a gui...

```
 table = new JTable(tableData,colNames);
 JScrollPane  scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Comment: why did You say "is tricky beast" ? All is in mainstream JDBC

Comment: I can use Oracles SQL developer with zero issues. Getting java to  find the data i want in a derby database has caused me to loose days of my life

Comment: In order to use derby in java you have to learn allot they do not teach in my Java college classes. Couple that with a google search of how to use derby in java and your are flooded with old info that has been outdated and just plain does not work

Comment: For example Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DEMO.Table1");
        
        while (rs.next()) {
        String s = rs.getString("Name");
        float n = rs.getFloat("Age");
        System.out.println(s + "   " + n);
    }
 taken from http://wiki.netbeans.org/GetStartedwithJavaDB which will be the wrong thing to be doing

Comment: me opposite: Derby works from first shot. Betwwen 3 java sql databases is the most 'classic'. I never use `resultset.last()` ... `resultset.first()` pattern in one way algorithm (and so, more costly construction)